# using apportable to port to android in portrait view

Tags: android, ios, portrait, apportable

I made a game using the [tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/369/build-your-own-flappy-bird-with-spritebuilder-and), in iphone and ipad the orientation is portrait, however when ported to android, the screen orientation is always in landscape. Is there anyway to force android to play it in portrait?

I have infoplist key in Release.final :

```
 "infoplists": [
    "./Source/Resources/Info.plist"
],
```

Also info.plist shows :

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Comment: There is no need for the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` key, since `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete or move FlappyFly.approj and apportable will ask you whether you want portrait or default.  I ran into some other problems however.  When you click restart, the app crashes.  Also the background is black. Also there is a white square in the upper right initially that then goes away. Also some of the obstacles spawn to the left of the flying object after you've already passed them and stick there.

Answer (score 2):

Add "portrait" to the "FEATURES" section of configuration.json

Comment: i have added "FEATURES" : ["portrait"], under either "config": {} or "add_params" :{} . in both cases, the app still open in landscape

Comment: Hey Paul, when adding portrait to the features I found that it opens it in portrait IF you are holding your device in portrait mode when you open the app. What is the correct way to force it to open in portrait mode all the time?

Comment: Just fixed it, I had landscape checked in XCode so it was allowing the app to open in landscape! Works great, apportable rocks!